# Casting an instance of an array list to another instance

Tags: java, class, loops, casting

I have two classes, Items and Monster. Monster is a subclass of Items. I am looping through the collection of item instances to see if they match a monster instance and if so, cast the item instance to a monster instance. However I am unsure how to cast a specific item in the arraylist to another type of class. Heres my code any help would be helpful.

```
 public void describe()
    {      
        int j = 0;

        while(j < iInstances.size())
        {
            if(iInstances.get(j).equals(mInstances.get(j)))
            {

            }
            iInstances.get(j).describe();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to increment `j` in your loop.

Answer (score 2):

`Monster monster = (Monster) iInstances.get(j);`

Comment: cast will fail if `iInstances.get(j)` holds a `Items` object. add check (`instanceof`) before casting.

Comment: If you put this inside the if statement though, this will never happen

Comment: @EugenHalca yes it is meant to be inside of if statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check each `Item` if it is an instance of class `Monster`, you can easily ask it for its instance and then cast to a `Monster`:

```
public void describe() {
    for (Item item : iInstances) {
        if (item instanceof Monster) {
            Monster monster = (Monster) item;
            // now do what you want with your monster
        }
    }
}
```